# CakePHP shell as cron permissions issue

Tags: ubuntu, cron

First to say that I know basics of Linux systems. I am familiar with cron jobs. I am using CakePHP shell as cronjob.

The script is using model's method to download pages from site user entered. Everything works fine but when I create cron as user *bokac* the script doesn't have the right privileges to create folders (I am guessing that) because if I delete cronjob for that user, and switch user to *www-data* and create the same cron there, the script works, and creates required folders.

How to make script do that with first user, *bokac* ? I am not sure what or who created user *www-data*. Any help appreciated.

Comment: did the folder in which the cron is working has permissions for the user `bokac`??

Comment: I am not sure where to find crontab. When I save it, it is in tmp dir, but there is no directory there for cron. Does that matter?

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598530/cron-job-and-folders-permissions-permission-denied)

Comment: I tried this solution, as I said, it works with crontab under _www-data_. I am not sure if that is a security risk maybe? Also when files are created, they appear locked to a _bokac_ user..

Comment: On many (not all) distributions, `www-data`is the user under which the Apache web server runs. This also means that everything done by Apache (especially including PHP scripts) will be done with the permissions of user `www-data` (and also group `www-data`) by default.So one work around is add user `bokac` to group `www-data` hope this helps :-)